# Trying to fill an array with data opened from files

Tags: python, arrays, file-io

the following is code I have written that tries to open individual files, which are long strips of data and read them into an array. Essentially I have files that run over 15 times (24 hours to 360 hours), and each file has an iteration of 50, hence the two loops. I then try to open the files into an array. When I try to print a specific element in the array, I get the error "'file' object has no attribute '**getitem**'". Any ideas what the problem is? Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
############################################
#
import csv
import sys
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
#
#############################################

level = input("Enter a level: ");
LEVEL = str(level);
MODEL = raw_input("Enter a model: ");  
NX = 360;
NY = 181;
date = 201409060000;
DATE = str(date);
#############################################

FileList = [];
data = [];

for j in range(1,51,1):
    J = str(j);
    for i in range(24,384,24):
            I = str(i);
            fileName = '/Users/alexg/ECMWF_DATA/DAT_FILES/'+MODEL+'_'+LEVEL+'_v_'+J+'_FT0'+I+'_'+DATE+'.dat';
            FileList.append(fileName);
            fo = open(fileName,"rb");
            data.append(fo);
            fo.close();
print data[1][1];
```

## print FileList;

EDITED TO ADD:
Below, find the CORRECT array that the python script should be producing (sorry it wont let me post this inline yet):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItSxd.png

The problem I now run into, is that the first three values in the first row of the output matrix are:

```
-7.090874    

-7.004936    

-6.920952
```

These values are actually the first three values of the 11th row in the array below, which is the how it should look (performed in MATLAB). The next three values the python script outputs (as what it believes to be the second row) are:

```
-5.255577    

-5.159874    

-5.064171
```

These values should be found in the 22nd row. In other words, python is placing the 11th row of values in the first position, the 22nd in the second and so on. I don't have a clue as to why, or where in the code I'm specifying it do this.

Comment: Please read this: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: In particular: don't put semicolons on the end of each line; don't arbitrarily mix different variable naming styles, indent consistently instead of haphazardly, and use `with` statements instead of `close`. As written, this doesn't look like Python to anyone experienced with Python, which slows down anyone trying to read it and help you.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what code you're using, we can't debug what's wrong with the code. And, since it's clearly not the code in your original question, you should post this as a new question, not edit this one. In your new question, give us a complete MCVE, with (stripped-down) runnable source and input (in text, not a screenshot), so if someone wants to just directly debug it instead of trying to reason through from first principles they can (which is often a faster way to get an answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're appending the file objects themselves to `data`, not their contents:

```
fo = open(fileName,"rb");
data.append(fo);
```

So, when you try to `print data[1][1]`, `data[1]` is a file object (a closed file object, to boot, but it would be just as broken if still open), so `data[1][1]` tries to treat that file object as if it were a sequence, and file objects aren't sequences.

---

It's not clear what format your data are in, or how you want to split it up.

---

If "long strips of data" just means "a bunch of lines", then you probably wanted this:

```
data.append(list(fo))
```

A file object *is* an iterable of lines, it's just not a sequence. You can copy any iterable into a sequence with the `list` function. So now, `data[1][1]` will be the second line in the second file.

(The difference between "iterable" and "sequence" probably isn't obvious to a newcomer to Python. The tutorial section on [Iterators](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) explains it briefly, the [Glossary](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable) gives some more information, and the ABCs in the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) module define exactly what you can do with each kind of thing. But briefly: An iterable is anything you can loop over. Some iterables are sequences, like `list`, which means they're indexable collections that you can access like `spam[0]`. Others are not, like `file`, which just reads one line at a time into memory as you loop over it.)

---

If, on the other hand, you actually imported `csv` for a reason, you more likely wanted something like this:

```
reader = csv.reader(fo)
data.append(list(reader))
```

Now, `data[1][1]` will be a list of the columns from the second row of the second file.

---

Or maybe you just wanted to treat it as a sequence of characters:

```
data.append(fo.read())
```

Now, `data[1][1]` will be the second character of the second file.

---

There are plenty of other things you could just as easily mean, and easy ways to write each one of them… but until you know which one you want, you can't write it.

Comment: That worked, thank you. I will take care to change the formatting as well. As you can tell, I'm very new to this. A new problem has emerged though, the data is appending correctly, except for the fact that the array is appending with the 11th iteration of the data in the first row, instead of the 1st iteration. I understand that this problem is because the data is indexed as ...1-9... instead of ...01-09. is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @agold2121: I don't understand what you mean `01-09` is either the numbers as `1-9` or an illegal range of octal numbers. Maybe you don't realize that indexes in Python start from 0, so the first row is `data[0]`, the second is `data[1]`, etc.?

Comment: Upon further inspection, the array is storing the 11th iteration of the file name in the first row, 22nd in the second row, 33rd in the third and so on. Where in my code am I telling it to do that?

Comment: @agold2121: Again, I don't understand what you mean. If you're still trying to solve the same problem, edit your question. If it's a new problem, create a new question. Either way, put an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question—stripped-down code and input, with desired and actual output.